# Why after change value in dictionary, all other value also changed too?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, key-value, iterable

Why after change an value in specified index in dictionary, all other index value also changed, why is this happened?

```py
with open(BotAccountFile, 'r') as account_file:
        for num, line in enumerate(account_file, 1):
            username = line.split(',')[0].strip()
            BotAccountsLinksList[num] = {'UserName': username, 'Password': line.split(',')[1].strip(),
                                         'CompletedDownload': False}

    BotLinksList = {}
    BotLinksList['LinkData'] = {}
    with open(BotDownloadURIsFile, 'r') as link_file:
        for item in BotAccountsLinksList:
            for num, line in enumerate(link_file, 1):
                BotLinksList['LinkData'][num] = {'Link': line.strip(), 'CompletedDownload': False}
            BotAccountsLinksList[item].update(BotLinksList)
```

And my dictionary:

```py
BotAccountsLinksList = {}

BotAccountsLinksList = {1: {'UserName': 'user1', 'Password': 'pass1',  
    'CompletedDownload': False, 'LinkData': {1: {'Link': 'www.yahoo.com',  
    'CompletedDownload': False}, 2: {'Link': 'www.google.com',  
    'CompletedDownload': False}}}, 2: {'UserName': 'user2', 'Password': 'pass2',  
    'CompletedDownload': False, 'LinkData': {1: {'Link': 'www.yahoo.com',  
    'CompletedDownload': False}, 2: {'Link': 'www.google.com',  
    'CompletedDownload': False}}}, 3: {'UserName': 'user3', 'Password': 'pass3',  
    'CompletedDownload': False, 'LinkData': {1: {'Link': 'www.yahoo.com',  
    'CompletedDownload': False}, 2: {'Link': 'www.google.com',  
    'CompletedDownload': False}}}, 3: {'UserName': 'user4', 'Password': 'pass4',  
    'CompletedDownload': False, 'LinkData': {1: {'Link': 'www.yahoo.com',  
    'CompletedDownload': False}, 2: {'Link': 'www.google.com',  
    'CompletedDownload': False}}}}
```

And I use this code to change just one value in index 1:

`BotAccountsLinksList[1]['LinkData'][1]['CompletedDownload'] = True # {'Link': 'www.yahoo.com', 'CompletedDownload': True}`

But after running this code, other index value also changed:

```py
BotAccountsLinksList = {1: {'UserName': 'user1', 'Password': 'pass1',  
    'CompletedDownload': False, 'LinkData': {1: {'Link': 'www.yahoo.com',  
    'CompletedDownload': True}, 2: {'Link': 'www.google.com',  
    'CompletedDownload': False}}}, 2: {'UserName': 'user2', 'Password': 'pass2',  
    'CompletedDownload': False, 'LinkData': {1: {'Link': 'www.yahoo.com',  
    'CompletedDownload': True}, 2: {'Link': 'www.google.com',  
    'CompletedDownload': False}}}, 3: {'UserName': 'user3', 'Password': 'pass3',  
    'CompletedDownload': False, 'LinkData': {1: {'Link': 'www.yahoo.com',  
    'CompletedDownload': True}, 2: {'Link': 'www.google.com',  
    'CompletedDownload': False}}}, 3: {'UserName': 'user4', 'Password': 'pass4',  
    'CompletedDownload': False, 'LinkData': {1: {'Link': 'www.yahoo.com',  
    'CompletedDownload': True}, 2: {'Link': 'www.google.com',  
    'CompletedDownload': False}}}}
```

*I'm using Python 3.8 on Windows 10 64-bit.*

Comment: Show more code. The problem must be somewhere else.

Comment: @RafalS i just use that line code to change and value in an index

Comment: I run your code and I get correct results. If that's the whole code then this is really werid.

Comment: @RafalS Not weird at all. If you give *your mom* flowers, are you also surprised that *your brother's mom* now has flowers? They're *the same person*, just referenced differently.

Comment: I get what a reference is, but the code uses only dict, string, number and bool literals.

Comment: @StefanPochmann its reference problem? (generator code(?))

Comment: @RafalS Ah, ok. Well, clearly he's not actually creating that large structure with that large literal but just presented it here like that.

Comment: Oh, right. @PashaAleayoob, again, could you show the whole code?

Comment: @RafalS Whole code added

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
BotAccountsLinksList[item].update(BotLinksList)
```

is doing

```
for k,v in BotLinksList.items():
    BotAccountsLinksList[item][k] = v
```

`BotLinksList` values will be shared across multiple `BotAccountsLinksList` keys. Don't reuse the same dict multiple times or do a deepcopy

```
import copy

BotAccountsLinksList[item].update(copy.deepcopy(BotLinksList))
```

Comment: thanks +1 for explain.you saved my time;)